# php and my sql search db error

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the code :-

```
<?php
 include 'include/header.php';
 include 'include/connect.php';
 mysql_select_db("search_db") or die("Couldn't select database.");

  $output = '';
  //collect

if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != "") {
 $searchq = $_POST['search'];
 $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%". 
 $searchq . "%' OR id LIKE '" . $searchq . "';");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0) {
    $output = 'There was no search results!';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $fname = $row ['name'];
        $id = $row ['id'];

        $output .= '<div>'.$name.' '.$id.'</div>';
    }
  }
     }
       ?> 
 <!--html-->
                     <form action="search.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
              <input type="submit"value="search">
```

I am trying to set up search in my website using  php and mysql I am getting an error like this    " An error has occurred - could not connect to the database."

Let me know search result code like name , user photo, description, type box anyone can help us appreciated

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli for connection as mysql functions are removed in php7

Comment: You should use mysqli . You can read here about it. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp